# Potential distribution and resistance of hollow sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electricity

> Cylindrical wires are connected to diametrically opposite points A and B of a weakly conducting homogeneous hollow sphere, between the ends A and B of which a constant potential difference U is maintained. Find the distribution of the potential $\varphi$ as a function of the angle $\theta$ (see picture). The angle at which the diameter of the base of each of the wires is visible from the center of the sphere O is $2\theta_0$.
> Calculate resistance of the sphere given the electrical conductance $\lambda$ and thickness of sphere $\delta$

[image: Schematic of electric circuit]

My attempt:
Assume $R$ is a radius of a sphere. We know that potential at point A is $\varphi_1$ (let's assume it's $0$), at B it's $\varphi_2$ (given the assumption it's equal to $U$).
Let's calculate potential in some point C on the sphere (because of sphere symmetry, its' position may be expressed in terms of $\theta$)
$\varphi(\theta) = \int_C^A \vec E \cdot \vec{dr}$
$I = \int \vec j d\vec S = \int \frac{\vec E}{\lambda} \pi R^2 sin(2\theta) d\theta$
And this is there I am stuck. It's not clear what to do next.
Looks like that calculating the resistance of sphere may be done after finding distribution of potential using $R = \frac U I$, but how to do that?

How should I solve this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say the potential at point A is $U$ and at point B it is 0. We will use the symbol $V$ for the potential in order to avoid confusion with the azimuthal angle $\varphi$. As you said, symmetry implies that the potential depends only on the polar angle $\theta$ from point A to the point of interest.

Now we know from the definition of conductivity that $J = 
\lambda E = -\lambda \nabla V$. In spherical coordinates,

$$ \nabla V = \hat{r} \frac{\partial V}{\partial r} + \frac{\hat\theta}{r} \frac{\partial V}{\partial \theta} + \frac{\hat\varphi}{r\sin\theta}\frac{\partial V}{\partial \varphi} = \frac{\hat\theta}{r}\frac{\partial V}{\partial \theta}$$

That is, $J = -(\lambda/r)(\partial V / \partial \theta)\hat\theta$.

We also have the continuity equation: $\nabla \cdot J = 0$. In spherical coordinates,

$$\begin{align}
\nabla \cdot J &=\frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r^2 J_r) + \frac{1}{r\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}(\sin\theta\ J_\theta) + \frac{1}{r\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}J_\phi \\
&= -\frac{\lambda}{r^2\sin\theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}(\sin\theta\ \partial V/\partial\theta)\end{align}$$

Using the fact that this quantity vanishes, we can determine a differential equation that must be satisfied by $V$. By integrating and using the boundary conditions, we can complete the first part (determining the potential as a function of $\theta$). This also allows us to determine $J$ everywhere on the sphere.

To get the resistance of the sphere, we use $R = U/I$. To get $I$, all we have to do is take some cross-section of the sphere and calculate the flux of $J$ across this surface.